# Query on local database file without sqlite

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

Is there any way to connect a database file in .net4 without using SQLite external dll?
Trying to clean up my previous application to avoid external files

```
SQLiteConnection sql_con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=\"c:\\ProgramData\\MyApplication\\DB.dat\";Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
sql_con.Open();
SQLiteCommand sql_cmd = sql_con.CreateCommand();
sql_cmd.CommandText = "select name from info where id = " + id;
SQLiteDataReader r = sql_cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Weird question, you don't want to use the SQLite libraries but you still want to read the sqlite file or do you want to substitute it?

Comment: I know its strange, but hoped that somehow i can do a single query on that file without any other dependencies

Comment: It is a binary file with its internal format that is understood by the appropriate library or perhaps from thirdy party apps. (IE there is a Firefox plugin). If you need to programmatically access that file, the SQLite libraries are the only sensible solution AFAIK.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL server compact (SQL CE) which also stores a database in a single file. Or the newest technology is SQL server LocalDB, which is also pretty similar in this respect. These component may have external dependencies, too, though, just like SQLite. So you do need to install something for SQL CE or LocalDB support. If you really don't want that, then you can store your data in a data store of your own, for example serialized in an XML file, and then you can use SQL-like LINQ queries to query that.